# ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: command-line, ssh, openssh

I have been trying the following command on the virtual machine in Ubuntu:

```
ssh root@10.0.2.15
```

But I keep in getting this response :

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection refused
```

I have checked my ssh status with this command :

```
service sshd status
```

And I got this result back:

[image: Screenshot showing, among other information, "Server listening on :: port 22"]

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the content of `etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use ssh with port option:

`ssh root@10.0.2.15 -p 2222`

**Edit**

This issue happens when you change your ssh server port to a non standard port like 2222 in ssh config file. (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` --> `Port 2222`)

Comment: I have one question ,why do you put -p 2222?

Comment: because your ssh server have listened on port 2222 but you connect to port 22.

Comment: you can change your ssh server listening port in this file: `/etc/sshd/sshd_config     ---> Port  22` and after that restart your ssh service. `systemctl restart ssh`